# Disable application functionality when missing assembly

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I'm building an application that uses the Oracle.DataAccess.dll to connect to a database to do some work.  The database access isn't necessary to perform 90% of what the application does and the application loads fine without the dll thanks to JIT loading. However, it does crash when accessing the specific part of the application that uses the dll when it's not present.

I'd like to be able to disable access to that form proactively when the dll is missing, is there any way to detect that dll at application load?

Update:

I was able to find a potential solution by doing

```
if (!File.Exists("Path to Oracle.DataAccess.dll"))
{
     toolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
}
```

Are there any better solutions out there?

Comment: Since you're dynamically loading the assembly, why not dynamically build the links to that part of the application when that assembly loads?

Comment: I guess I should clarify, the assembly is defined at design time as a project reference.  It's through C#'s own JIT loading that the load is actually deferred to when needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [Assembly.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.load.aspx) and see if it works; otherwise, perhaps [GetLoadedModules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getloadedmodules.aspx) may do what you need. A path search isn't going to work as it'd exclude the GAC and other places assemblies can be.